# How to uninstall exepackage where separate uninstaller executable to be invoked in wix

Tags: wix, burn

I am new to Wix. I have an exe package that installs fine while installing the wix bundle. While uninstalling the bundle exe package uninstall path is setting to the program data cache path but this exe has a different uninstall exe in program files. How can I set it up the uninstall path to the program file path?

```
    <ExePackage Id="exe" DisplayName="name" Name="path\test.exe" SourceFile="path\test.exe" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCondition="EXEPRESENT=0" InstallCommand="-y" DetectCondition="EXEPRESENT=1" UninstallCommand="[ProgramFiles64Folder]\path\Uninstall\setup.exe -uninstall"/>
```

but in the log I am seeing

```
    Applying execute package: EXE, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ECD26B99EA3992A1627A07921292F8C5380F0EB5\Bundle\test.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ECD26B99EA3992A1627A07921292F8C5380F0EB5\Bundle\test.exe" C:\Program Files\\path\Uninstall\setup.exe -uninstall'
```

which is making the exe install again instead of uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is implemented in WiX v4: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4755